# How to convert date to timestamp javascript

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

Im trying to create a new document in firestore using a cloud function. However i am unable to save the date as a timestamp rather, it's saved as a string currently.

**How it is right now**

[image]

**What i need to achieve**

[image]

**Snippet of my cloud function**

```
    await admin.firestore()
    .doc('/buyerProfile/'+response.buyerId)
    .collection('notifications')
    .add({
        'type':'New response',
        'responseId':response.responseId,
        'requestId':response.requestId,
        'date': Date(Date.now()),
        'compressedImgUrl':response.compressedImgUrl,
        'description':response.description,
        'requestPaidFor':request.data().isPaidFor
    }).then(()=>console.log('Notification created'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use to get timestamp `new Date().getTime();`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now#return_value

Answer (score 0):

You don't have `new` keyword before `Date` constructor which will indeed return a string. If you want a Date object try this:

```
date: new Date() // Date object of current time
```

If you want to store the timestamp as number then pass `Date.now()`

You can check the same in a browser console:

[image]

---

You can also use `serverTimestamp()` method instead:

```
date: admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
```

Comment: This gives a number

Comment: @Bright try using `serverTimestamp()` ?

Comment: I know where your coming from but when i do that, its saved as a number on firestore

Comment: Let me try the serverTimestamp()

Comment: @Bright oh you don't have `new`... just try `date': new Date(),`

Answer (score 0):

just do it like this:

```
      let today = new Date();

  let timestamDate = Date.parse(today) / 1000;
```

and your date will be converted to timestamp

Answer (score 0):

This worked for my case, i had to import Timestamp from firebase admin

```
const { timeStamp, time } = require("console");
...
'date': timeStamp.now(),
```

Answer (score 0):

Firestore stores date/time values in its own `Timestamp` format.

There are two options:

1. If you want to capture the client-side time, use [`Timestamp.now()`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/Timestamp.html#.now), so:

   ```
   'date': Firestore.Timestamp.now(),
   ```
2. If you want to capture the server-side time, use:

   ```
   'date': admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
   ```

Answer (score 0):

import { serverTimestamp } from 'firebase/firestore';

and replace:  <'date': Date(Date.now())>

with <'date': serverTimestamp()>

this should solve your problem